# Проблемы с CORS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Всем привет. Пишу проект на React + Node.js + Express.js + Самописная БД. Когда делаю запрос на "api/accounts/register" получаю вот эту ошибку:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8200/api/accounts/sign' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Если ввести mode: "no-cors" на сервере получаю пустой body.
Обработчик запроса на сервере:

```js
app.post("/api/accounts/sign", parser, (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body)
  let status = { ok: false, token: "" };
  if (request.body.name.length > 0 & request.body.password.length > 0) {
    Requests.check(request.body, status, "accounts");
    if (status.ok) {
      response.status(200).send({ ok: true, status: 200, message: "Authorization", token: status.token });
      authorization = true;
    } else response.status(500).send({ ok: false, status: 500, message: "Data is not correct" });
  };
});
```

Fetch post Запрос на стороне клиента:

```js
  function authorizationEnter() {
    async function inner() {
      let request = await fetch(`http://localhost:8200/api/accounts/sign`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: authorizationBase.name,
          password: authorizationBase.password
        }),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        }
      });
      let response = await request.json();
      if (request.status == 200) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".sign_input").forEach(input => input.classList.add("valid"));
        document.querySelectorAll(".sign_input").forEach(input => input.classList.remove("notValid"));
        window.location.href = "/news";
        localStorage.setItem("TOKEN", response.token);
      } else {
        document.querySelectorAll(".sign_input").forEach(input => input.classList.remove("valid"));
        document.querySelectorAll(".sign_input").forEach(input => input.classList.add("notValid"));
      };
    };
    inner();
  };
```

по поводу headers: "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8", не работает в любом случае, хоть так хоть просто "application/json"

Пожалуйста, нужна помощь. Всем спасибо.

Comment: добавьте в ответ заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Возможно, придётся заполнить ещё несколько заголовков `Access-Control-Allow-...`

Comment: В смысле в ответе? Где там можно впихнуть эти заголовки?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите middleware [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
npm install cors --save
```

При создании вашего express-приложения подключите этот middleware так:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: Да, сработало. Но помог мне с этим друг) Но всё же огромное спасибо за ответ :3