# Как в Express JS использовать app.use() вместе с express.json() и function(req, res, next){}

Tags: frontend, express, backend, fetch

у меня появилась проблема на стороне сервера. Дело в том что, я написал Бекендную часть сайта и код выглядит вот так

```
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const port    = 5000;

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('db.sqlite');

app.use(express.json())

app.post( ... ) //Здесь все работает, и не должно никак связанно с проблемой

async function startApp(){
    try {
        app.listen(port, () => console.log('SERVER STARTED ON PORT', port))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("[!] ", e)
    }
}
startApp()
```

Это рабочее состояние кода, проверялось с помощью postmen и результат выводился именно такой, какой мне нужен.

Но когда я начал работать с фронтендом

```
function sendRequests(method, url, body = null) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify( body ),
        headers: headers
    }).then( response => {
        return response.json()
    } )
};

var requireUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/'

sendRequests('POST', requireUrl, { lang: "ru" })
    .then( data => console.log(data) )
    .catch( err => console.log("[!]", err) )
```

После этого появилась ошибка описанная вот здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Я нашел решение, оно описано здесь https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Но тогда после этого мой код выглядит так

```
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const port    = 5000;

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('db.sqlite');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
)

app.post( ... ) //Здесь все работает, и не должно никак связанно с проблемой

async function startApp(){
    try {
        app.listen(port, () => console.log('SERVER STARTED ON PORT', port))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("[!] ", e)
    }
}
startApp()
```

Теперь мой код не работает.[image]

И в функции `sendRequests` срабатывает `.catch`

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: В общем как можно объеденить вместе `express.json()` и `function(req, res, next)`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1288257/2659

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с CORS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288034/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-cors)