# Ошибка при получении данных из axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

Во время попытки получения данных из *axios* получаю странную ошибку:

[image: скриншот Ошибок]

Код запроса:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000';const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);React.useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get('/api/products');
  setProducts(result.data);
};
fetchData();}, []);
```

Comment: проблема сервера, надо разрешить высылание запросов с разных доменов в настройках cors

Comment: ага, а как это сделать?

Comment: ну та зависимо на чем написан сервер

Comment: нода, а точнее express

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288034/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-cors?rq=1