# Как передать данные с Vue в Node.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

У меня есть frontend написанный на Vue.js и есть back-end написанный на Node.js
Как передать данные с формы в обработчик? У меня клиент и backend работает на разных портах, поэтому когда я передаю данные с формы они не куда не попадают.

Vue.js

```
  <template>
<div>
  <form action="/create"  method="POST">
    <input name="name" placeholder="логин" v-model="name1">
    <input name="password" placeholder="пароль" v-model="pass1">
    <button type="submit" @click="register()">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>

</template>
```

Js (node.js)

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const express = require("express");
const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({extended: false});
const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({ //подключение к БД
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'usersimper',
  password: ''
})

connection.connect(err => { //Проверка на ошибки при подключение
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  else{
    console.log('БД запущенна!')
  }
})

app.get("/create", function(req, res){ 
  connection.query("INSERT INTO `users`(`login`, `password`, `name`, `lastname`, `role`, `status`, `br`) VALUES ('a','b','c','d','f','1','2')", (err, result) =>{
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    else{
      result = result[1]['login']
      console.log(result)
    }
  })
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log("Сервер запущен..."));
```

Но если я захожу на сервер node.js то в базе создается юзер. Надо именно с vue сервера отправлять данные.

Comment: `<form action="http://localhost:3000/create"  method="POST">` и полключите `cors` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1288257/2659

Comment: и обработчик `app.get("/create"` должен хоть что-то возвращать в ответ, примерно `if (err) res.status(500).send('Something broke!');` и `res.json(result)`

Comment: @nörbörnën Хорошо. попробую, спасибо

Comment: Использовать отправку form на фронте где используете вью.. это жестоко по отношению к юзеру :) используйте fetch (если на другой домен запрос, прикрутите cors)

Comment: +.. если сервер делает более чем 1 запрос в БД - реклмендую sequelize, а так же синтаксис async\await, код будет гаразда более читабельным... Просто рекомендация, не требующая воплощения