# Проставил заголовок, но все равно получаю ошибку CORS

Tags: node.js, express

Использую express в node js приложении, проставляю хедеры

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

Использую router

```
const Router = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const router = new Router();
const authMiddleware = require("../middleware/login.middleware");
const secretKey = "adfaslsfa;lsaf";

router.get("/auth", authMiddleware, function (req, res) {
  try {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: 1 }, secretKey, {
      expiresIn: 120 * 120,
    });
    return res.json({
      token,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send({ message: "Server error" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Использую в главном файле после проставления заголовков

```
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
```

С фронта при загрузке компонента после авторизации шлю следующую функцию

```
auth({ commit }) {
      const isLoggedIn = axios
        .get("http://localhost:3333/auth", {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            commit("SET_USER", true);
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          return false;
        });
      return isLoggedIn;
    },
```

И получаю ошибку CORS что нельзя по этому урлу суваться

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3333/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Что-то такое встречал ранее, решилось простым подключением SSL (https)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1288257/2659

Comment: @Jour спасибо, помогло, но сейчас другая проблема - при загрузке приложения токен приходит, все ок, но в защите роутов состояние user, которое зависит от токена в том числе, имеет false, хотя когда смотрю во vuedevtools, то там user true. Как это поправить? Не успевает роутер дождаться токена? Почему обновленный state не смотрит